# SVG text element, property writing-mode: tb, does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, text, svg, cross-browser

I'm doing an SVG, I need to show a measure and I want to put text vertically, using writing-mode: tb; everything perfect in chrome, IE, Opera and Safari but in firefox the text appears horizontal.

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="100,100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <style type="text/css">
        .cota-text {
          fill: #000;
          font-size: 10px; 
          text-anchor: middle;
        }

        .cota-vertical { 
            writing-mode: tb; 
        }
     </style>
     <text x="10" y="10" class="cota-text cota-vertical">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

I have no clue what could be causing the issue. Could someone please help me troubleshoot?

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yf4nduob/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical text in d3 (not rotated)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437256/vertical-text-in-d3-not-rotated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible duplicate of [vertical text in d3 (not rotated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437256/vertical-text-in-d3-not-rotated)**

Citing from there:

> The 'writing-mode' property is supposed to change the first aspect without affecting the others, but as you discovered [**it's not implemented at all in Firefox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode), while IE rotates the text but doesn't respect the horizontal-glyph rule.

Here are three possible ways to [get vertical text in SVG though cross-browser](http://jsfiddle.net/hx5Th/11/) from the same answer.

Among those:

```
//Blue text, uses d3 to create a series of tspans//
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 40)
  .attr("y", 40)
  .attr("font-size", 50)
  .attr("id", "title")
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("transform", "translate(300,0)")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .selectAll("tspan")
      .data("Top 100 Mentions".split(""))
  .enter().append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("dy", "0.8em")
      .text(function(d){return d;});
```